# Visual studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

How to show output on console in visual studio 2010 window goes within second.

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: I used c++ language

Comment: @ShubhamParmar : Check my answer

Answer (score 1):

if you run without debugging (Ctrl+F5) then by default it prompts your to press return to close the window

If you have a C++ app  you need to explicitly set the Subsystem to `Console` under `Configuration Properties / Linker / System`.